# eight parts intuition and experience with two parts theory -- what does that really mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Example with a context:

> We should conclude by saying that there is no law that says that a database is always more useful or efficient if the tables have a high degree of normalization. These issues are more subjective than objective and must be dealt with as a design issue on an ad hoc basis. In fact, it appears that the best procedure for good database design is to mix **eight parts intuition and experience with two parts theory**. Hopefully, our discussion of normalization has given you a general feeling for the issues involved and will provide a good jumping-off place if you decide to study these somewhat complicated issues in greater depth.

What does that really mean? Is that a play on words or something?

Comment: Since you have "***8** parts X*" and "***2** parts Y*", you have `8+2`, which is 10, parts total, `8/10`, or 80%, of which is *X*, and `2/10`, or 20%, of which is *Y*. In other words, he is saying database optimization is 80% art and 20% science. The part of database performance you can control through application of generic rules is relatively small.

Comment: This is basically another way to mention the [80-20 rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_principle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In fact, it appears that the best procedure for good database design is to mix eight parts intuition and experience with two parts theory.

It means that when you design a database you should give preference to your own intuition and experience - and to a big extent - 80% (8 out of 10 parts). You should also take into account your theoretical knowledge of database design, but on a much smaller scale: 20% (2 parts out of 10).

In other words, intuition and experience are more important in practical database design than theoretical knowledge, and the approximate ratio of their importance is 80% vs 20%.

Here, it's clear from the context that the total number of "*parts*" implied is ten: 8 + 2 = 10, and our most common numeral system is based on 10.

In some expressions with the word "parts" the implied total number might differ from 10:

> We went out on a Friday night and returned *three parts drunk*.
>   To fear love is to fear life, and those who fear life are already *three parts dead*.

Here, the implied total is 4, because *three-quarters* is a fraction familiar to the English ear ([see here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/92680/48335)). The meanings are "we returned 75% drunk" and "who fear love are 75% dead".

Comment: So, basically the author just uses the concept of "scale of one to ten" to make his point. I gotcha.

Comment: @CookieMonster - yes, he implies that the total number of parts is 10.

Comment: Re your point about the implied total number not always being 10, I suspect most native speakers would routinely "normalise" OP's example to **4** parts intuition - contrasting with **1** part theory, which [as this related ELU question indicates](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92678/), is assumed to be **1 part of something other than theory** if the actual number or nature of the "other" parts is unspecified.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - thanks for the clarification! I've been wondering how many total parts were implied in "[three parts drunk](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Moon_and_Sixpence/Chapter_XLVII)" ever since I met the expression in "The Moon and Sixpence". The "one missing part" hypothesis makes it clearer.

Comment: As I pointed out in my ELU answer, when there's an implicit "unspecified" single part, there are nearly always **3** or **9** specified parts. You'll rarely see ***four** parts drunk*, or ***six** parts dead*, for example.